# How to create a new wordpress category in front end

Tags: wordpress, categories, frontend

I want my users to be able to post from the front end, and to put the post in a category they created. I got everything in my form except the possibility to create a new category.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<?php wp_create_category( $cat_name, $parent ); ?>
```

pass variable

```
wp_create_category($category);
```

or ,

hook the **create_category** action

Comment: Ok, i'm sure this is the way to go, but i don't seem to be able to work it in a form. Can you give me an example of how to do it? Or is this asking too much? I'd understand if this is the end of the line, and i'm on my own from here :)

Comment: well.. see my other answer, the comment form here is too short for the code.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you use POST

```
//Checking if category already there
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( $_POST['newcat'] );

//If not create new category
if($cat_ID == 0) {
    $cat_name = array('cat_name' => $_POST['newcat']);
    wp_insert_category($cat_name);
}

//Get ID of newly created category
$new_cat_ID = get_cat_ID($_POST['newcat']);

// Create post object
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $headline,
    'post_content' => $body,
    'post_excerpt' => $excerpt,
    'post_date' => $date,
    'post_date_gmt' => $date,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_category' => array($new_cat_ID)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $new_post );'
```

you can also ty this : `$newcat = $_POST['newcat'] and then just replace with $newcat in the code`
which maybe looks better :-)

note that `wp_insert_category()` and `wp-create_categoy()` has teh same function as far as you are concerned (IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Category from the front side than there is one easy way: (100% Working)

`wp_insert_term('Category Name', 'texonomy_type');`

Example:
`wp_insert_term('National', 'category');`

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function(){
   wp_create_category( 'Custom Category 1' );
   wp_create_category( 'Custom Category 2' );
});
```